# Drop-in CSS templates for mobile sites?

Tags: css, templates, mobile

Has anyone got any up-to-date examples of (or sources for) CSS templates that work across mobile devices?

They will ideally be very simple, the aim is to get something up and running with minimum fuss / effort, rather than catering to the individual whims of every device (or every bell and whistle).

Other related questions on SO are nearly 5 years old.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap... HTML5BP... if you want full ready to use templates.  If you want responsive frameworks, Columnal... CSS Grid... XY.css... Skeleton...

There are numerous others.

Comment: Michael, I've seen HTML5BP which has loads of nice CSS but it doesn't include any templates from what I can see?

Comment: I've found a few before with some extensive google searching, there is no official template site for html5 bp.  They are just community made things that people have made available, not necessarily super easy to come by.